# How to reset a select dropdown using springform:options and save null value

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, jsp

I have the following dropdown box created for the user to select a specific year:

```
<springform:select id="firstYear" path="member.attributes[firstYear].value" value=" " tabindex="3">
    <option disabled="disabled" value=" " selected="selected">Select year:</option>
    <springform:options id="years" items="${years}"/>
 </springform:select>
```

However, I want to set so that if a user checks a particular checkbox, this dropdown is cleared and a blank value is saved to the DB. Currently it is saving the first value in the array that is `${years}` which is not desirable. Here is the javascript I have tried using to clear it:

```
$("#firstYear option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#firstYear").selectedIndex=-1;
```

I have also tried setting the value of `firstYear` to `" "` but this didn't work either.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value to the dropdown, so when a time to save it to database it will take that value.

```
$("#firstYear").val("");
```

It will set an empty value to the dropdown. Also note, that empty values are treated some databases as `NULL`. Blank values contains at least one blank symbol and it's not empty string.

Comment: This seems to do nothing, it just keeps the same value it was at before. In the UI it is reset, but the old value is still stored to the DB.

Comment: Yeah, if I use this alone it resets the select box in the UI, but the value in the DB is not reset - it still holds the year value it had.

Comment: The process of communication with database is very long and pass through several layers, so when the value comes into database it might change, you should debug and test it for each layer separately.

Comment: When the dropdown changes, the old option seems to remain selected in the springform:options list (in the source, but not visibly) - this value is then passed to the backend. The java it handling the values correctly, but is being given the wrong value.

Comment: Got it working, needed to have it as " " with a space rather than empty. you did point me in the right direction though, thanks!